# .get and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a new Python programmer and I was reading up on the .get method for dictionaries, so I tried to use it for myself. I tried some very simple code:

```
h = dict()
h.get('a', 1)
print (h)
```

And the interpreter returned only:

```
{}
```

I know the .get method returns the default value that you provide it if it can't find the key that you asked for, but does it actually go and create a new key and bucket in the dictionary? If so, why doesn't my code return the new item? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't create the new item. Try `print(h.get('a', 1))` it will print `1` without modifying the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `get` does not add an entry to the dict if one doesn't exist. It makes no modifications.

```
>>> h = dict()
>>> h.get('a', 1)
1
>>> h
{}
```

The same goes for `[]` when reading from the dict; it will throw an error for non-existent keys. This is different from C++, where `[]` will add entries if they aren't there already.

```
>>> h['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
>>> h
{}
```

But know that Python can differentiate between reads and writes. Assigning to a non-existent key will create it, even though reading a non-existent key raises an exception.

```
>>> h['a'] = 1
>>> h
{'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

`h.get('a', 1)` will never insert `1` into `h`. If you want a method that inserts the default value when no value already exists, you want `setdefault`:

```
h = {}
h.setdefault('a', 1)
print h  # prints {'a': 1}
h.setdefault('a', 2)
print h  # still prints {'a': 1}
```

Comment: `get` *never* inserts any value into a dict, whether there's an existing value or not - it only returns the value which the key refers to, or the default value (1 in the OP's example) instead.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake. I didn't realize that I had to assign it to the key in the dictionary, even if that key doesn't exist yet. Still learning! Thank you.

Comment: @MikeVella: That's what I'm saying, though I suppose the current wording could be interpreted as saying that it *does* insert the value if another value already exists. Rephrasing...

Answer (score 0):

The `'a'` key does not exist and so the value `1` is returned instead. This is the behaviour of the `get()` method: The `get` method will return the value corresponding to the key, or the second parameter you pass to it (1 in your case) instead.

If you were to set the `'a'` key the behaviour would be different:

```
In [10]: h['a']=1

In [11]: h
Out[11]: {'a': 1}

In [12]: h.get('a',3)
Out[12]: 1
```

Refer to [This documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) explaining how the `get()` method works if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

`dictName.get()` is a similar to a `try...catch`. If the value does not exist, which would normally return an exception, it will return another value in its place.

```
h = {}
h.get('a', 1)
print h
```

`h.get('a', 1)` does not perform an action to `h`; it merely returns a value that you can (re)assign to a(nother) variable or test/print, etc.

```
h = {}
print h.get('a', 1)
```

. . .will return `1` since `h['a']` does not exist. However. . .

```
h = {}
h['a'] = 0
print h.get('a', 1)
```

. . .will return `0` since `h['a']` does exist.